# Migration from Backbone to AngularJS - how difficult it is?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, angularjs, refactoring

I'm developing a big project in Backbone (around 8000 lines of javascript, excluding external libraries) and I'm considering  a migration to AngularJS.

Currently I have a lot of code that handles DOM changes, binding and unbinding of events. I'm using Mustache for template rendering. Most data is loaded with AJAX, and stored in Backbone models, some of which use BackboneRelational. I'm using about 10 little jQuery plugins to do fancy UI stuff.

I'm determined to do this migration, however I'm worried about my deadlines. So the questions are:

1. How long can it take to rewrite it using AngularJS? Maybe someone can share his experience.
2. Is it possible to start using Angular right now, and implement new functionalities with it, without causing headaches when we need to interact with the Backbone part?
3. If I'll decide to do this refactoring after the deadline, what practices would you recommend to make the code easier to migrate?

Comment: Although your question is interesting it is probably overly broad

Comment: I'm looking into doing the same thing. What did you end up doing? Mind sharing your experience?

Comment: I think that it was a good idea to move to Angular. The code is much simpler and we have some tests. However, we wanted also to change whole project structure (separate GUI from API) and to divide all HTML, JS and CSS to small, independent modules, and this took us much longer than we expected. So my suggestion is to focus on getting fully-working version in Angular ASAP, and leave all other refactors for later. Cheers :)

Comment: 3 years later: "around 8000 lines of javascript" doesn't seem like a "big project" anymore. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ported a large 5k+ lines of BB code to Angular. I did this port when I was first starting with Angular and if I remember right, I did it over a weekend and then 3 days. So it was done in 5 days approx. You have to note that I wrote the whole BB application ( all of the 5k lines as well .. ) so it was easier for me to port.

You could perhaps mix BB and Angular initially ( develop new parts in Angular and slowly port BB parts over.. ) but I would suggest that if you can, then do the porting of the complete app first.

As a general rule, all your Backbone Models and Collections should go into services ( of the same name perhaps ? ) . Porting html and Mustache templates should be a piece of cake. The part that would be slightly tricky is your jquery plugins. But if they are simple ones then you will be able to use the angular-ui jquery passthrough ( http://angular-ui.github.io/ ).

Comment: That answer was removed!

Comment: Which means that for a medium size app, it would take *too many days* to port. Backbone and AngularJS are two completely different models and frameworks. You should first consider if you really really want to move to Angular...

Comment: ganaraj and @daniel.gindi A year later now, which framework would you use for a mid-sized project?

Comment: I would still prefer BB. More straightforward, no "black magic". You have much more control. - But if you are into the "popular" stuff, go with Angular.js. It IS powerful, as long as you do not need real complicated code.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I would still go with Angular. Having worked with it, I dont see any black magic. I have full control for complicated things and simple things are extremely easy.